# how to get the current date as YYYYMMDD in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am using the following code:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as time]
         '[clj-time.coerce :as tc]
         '[clj-time.format :as f])
 (f/unparse (f/formatter "yyyyMMdd") time/now)
```

But it throws the following error.

```
caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clj_time.core$now cannot be cast to org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
```

Comment: I don't have clj_time handy, but I suspect the issue is that you are using the function `now` as a value, when what you really need to do is call it `(time/now)` to get the return value.

Answer (score 2):

unparse function takes 2 arguments. First is the format,which should be an instance of org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter, which you create correctly by calling

```
 (f/formatter "yyyyMMdd")
```

the second argument is date time, which should be an instance of org.joda.time.DateTime and here you are doing small mistake. Instead of passing DateTime you are passing clojure function time/now, what you should do is to call the function like this

```
(f/unparse (f/formatter "yyyyMMdd") (time/now))
```